# Next Build failure with seemingly useless error message

Tags: webpack, build, next.js, vercel

I was migrating a project over from Heroku to Vercel to take advantage of Next.js. This isn't my first time using Next, but I've never come across a bug like this before.

I was able to build it last night and it worked fine, but somewhere along the line I wound up getting this error message:

```
HookWebpackError: Unexpected '/'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.
    at makeWebpackError (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:41630:9)
    at /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:25321:12
    at eval (eval at create (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:140036:10), <anonymous>:48:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
-- inner error --
Error: Unexpected '/'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.
    at /Users/bigsexy/Desktop/currentProjects/portfolio_on_next/static/css/1ec7d2389c57fd3d.css:425:1
    at Root._error (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:95188)
    at Root.error (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:141043)
    at Parser.error (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:103534)
    at Parser.unexpected (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:104020)
    at Parser.combinator (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:102267)
    at Parser.parse (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:109511)
    at Parser.loop (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:108916)
    at new Parser (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:95045)
    at Processor._root (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:111925)
    at Processor._runSync (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:112432)
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
Error: Unexpected '/'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.
    at /Users/bigsexy/Desktop/currentProjects/portfolio_on_next/static/css/1ec7d2389c57fd3d.css:425:1
    at Root._error (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:95188)
    at Root.error (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:141043)
    at Parser.error (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:103534)
    at Parser.unexpected (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:104020)
    at Parser.combinator (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:102267)
    at Parser.parse (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:109511)
    at Parser.loop (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:108916)
    at new Parser (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:95045)
    at Processor._root (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:111925)
    at Processor._runSync (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/cssnano-simple/index.js:195:112432)
```

I dug through every single file and can not find what this is talking about, so I'm guessing it's coming from an npm package? Is there a way to save the build files from a failed build so I can examine the `static/css/1ec...css` file? ? I've tried running the build with the `--debug` flag and it doesn't provide anymore information.

I would post code snippets but I don't even know where to look, so here's the repo for anyone with any ideas.

https://github.com/igloo1505/portfolio_on_next

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a leftover closing comment tag here: https://github.com/igloo1505/portfolio_on_next/blob/main/css/App.css#L429